# Does sitecore 10.1 support wffm(webform for marketers)?

Tags: wffm

Getting error on adding wffm form rendering on presentation details.Tried to install wffm modules but nothing worked at my end.Can anyone tell me does sitecore 10.1 support wffm forms?

Answer (score 5):

No.

WFFM 9.0 update-2 supports up to XP 9.0 update-2. No further releases of WFFM has been made.

Full information here: [Web Forms for Marketers – compatibility tables](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0779556)

Answer (score 0):

**No
It is deprecated from Sitecore 9.1.**

You have to rebuild those WFFM forms into Sitecore Forms and to achieve the additional form elements you can use  [Sitecore From Extension Module](https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions)
or you can write your own [customization from here](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-form-element.html).